# Choosing a random name from a list in a fun way (Python)

Tags: python, list, random, printing

So I would like pick a random name from a list and slowly reveal the winner, here it what I have so far:

```
import time
import random

names = ['Isaac', 'Matthew', 'Cameron', 'Andy', 'Rob']
blanks=''

winner =random.choice(names)
print(winner)

for i in range(len(winner)):
  blanks+= '_'

print(blanks)


from random import shuffle

def shuffle_word(word):
  word = list(word)
  shuffle(word)
  return ''.join(word)

scrambled = shuffle_word(winner)
print(scrambled)
```

I want the code to print the _ _ _ _ _ first and then reveal the missing letters of the scrambled name one by one using time.sleep() to make it more exciting. One the full scrambled name is revealed, I'd like to 'unscramble' the name and print the winner.

Could anyone help me do this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is more of a "please do this for me" than a StackOverflow question. That said, what you need is a display library like [urwid](http://urwid.org/).

Answer (score -1):

Try the below snippet. Add this at the last if your code and also understand the code so that it would be easier for you to Modify it if in case:

```
for i in range(0, len(scrambled)):
    print(scrambled[:i]+'_'*(len(scrambled)-i))
    time.sleep(3)
print(scrambled)
```